# complex numbers

Tags: limits, complex-numbers

I know that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ with $ab\neq0$, $f(a)f(b)\neq0$ and the complex numbers:

$$ z = a^2 + f(a)i $$
$$ w = b^2 - f(b)i $$

$$|\bar w + z| = |w - \bar z|$$

1)Prove that $w\cdot z$ is an imaginary number

2)Calculate the limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(a)x^3 - f(b)x + 5}{f(b)x^2 + f(a)x - 3}$$

Comment: By $a*b!=0$ you mean $a*b\neq 0$, correct?  The LaTeX for $\neq$ is "\neq"

Comment: i squared the 3rd equation and got to w conjugate * z conjugate + wz = 0

Comment: @Nick Then you are almost done - what does $\overline {wz}=-wz$ imply?

Comment: @Nick If you've figured it out, [feel free to post an answer (and accept it)](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2637/policy-on-accepting-my-own-answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. For any complex numbers $z,w$ we have 
   $$\operatorname{Re}(wz)  = \frac12 (|\bar w+z|^2-| w-\bar z|^2)$$
2. The limit 
   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(a)x^3 - f(b)x + 5}{f(b)x^2 + f(a)x - 3} 
   = \lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(a)x - f(b)/x^2 + 5/x^3}{f(b) + f(a)/x - 3/x^2} 
   $$
   does not exist (as a finite number).